# How to handle error in Step Functions ECS task error code taskfailedtostart

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-step-functions

I have a step function which has an ecs task to run.

All my step functions states monitored and error handled by catch option.

But this error `taskfailedtostart` error is coming when one ecs container doesn't have IP address to run a container. I solved the IP issue.. but I can't handle this `taskfailedtostart` error using step functions catch block..

Any suggestions to handle the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `StringToJson` in a `Pass` state, you can switch your retry or catch logic based on the task failure type

See the example below where it retries the task based on the StoppedReason

```
{
  "Version": "1.0",
  "Comment": "Run AWS Fargate task",
  "TimeoutSeconds": 900,
  "StartAt": "Run Fargate Task",
  "States": {
    "Run Fargate Task": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
        "Cluster": "<Cluster-ARN>",
        "TaskDefinition": "<TaskDef-ARN>",
        "Group.$": "$$.Execution.Name",
        "NetworkConfiguration": {
          "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
            "Subnets": [
              "<Subnet-1>",
              "<Subnet-2>",
              "<Subnet-3>"
            ],
            "AssignPublicIp": "ENABLED",
            "SecurityGroups": [
              "<SecurityGroup-ID>"
            ]
          }
        },
        "Overrides": {
          "ContainerOverrides": [
            {
              "Name": "<Container-Name>",
              "Environment": [
                {
                  "Name": "<Environment-Variable-Name-To-Override>",
                  "Value": "<Environment-Variable-Value-To-Override>"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "End": true,
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.TaskFailed"
          ],
          "Next": "Cause to Json"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Cause to Json": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "Cause.$": "States.StringToJson($.Cause)"
      },
      "Next": "Retry or Finish"
    },
    "Retry or Finish": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.Cause.StoppedReason",
          "StringMatches": "ResourceInitializationError: *",
          "Next": "Run Fargate Task"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Fail"
    },
    "Fail": {
      "Type": "Fail"
    }
  }
}
```